# Split Column into Unknown Number of Columns by Delimiter in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have this table with strings delimiter "+"

```
ID  Products                
1   A + B + C + D + E ... 
2   A + F + G
3   X + D
```

I would like to return in this format

```
ID  Products                 Product 1  Product 2  Product 3 Product 4 Product 5 product... 
1   A + B + C + D + E ...      A           B          C          D          E       ...
2   A + F + G                  A           F          G
3   X + D                      X           D
1   D + C + C + D + E          D           C          C          D          E
```

How I can reproduce this in Pandas Dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with regex `'\s+\+\s+'` -  it means one or more whitesapces, escaped `+`, one or more whitespaces, then change columns names by [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html) and last add to original by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df1 = df['Products'].str.split('\s+\+\s+', expand=True).add_prefix('Product').fillna('')
df = df.join(df1)
print (df)
   ID           Products Product0 Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4
0   1  A + B + C + D + E        A        B        C        D        E
1   2          A + F + G        A        F        G                  
2   3              X + D        X        D
```

Also if necessary change column names:

```
d = lambda x: f'Product{x+1}'
df = (df.join(df['Products'].str.split('\s+\+\s+', expand=True)
                            .rename(columns=d)
                            .fillna('')))
print (df)
   ID           Products Product1 Product2 Product3 Product4 Product5
0   1  A + B + C + D + E        A        B        C        D        E
1   2          A + F + G        A        F        G                  
2   3              X + D        X        D
```